# PHP regex ignore files that start with double __underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have tried, but I simply can't wrap my head around regex in PHP. I need a regex that does the following:

- ignores files that start with double __underscore. *(for example __file.jpg)*
- ignores files that end with "thumb". *(for example somethumb.jpg or thumb.jpg)*
- ignores all file types but gif|jpg|png|jpeg

I have the following for now, which seems to fulfill #2 and #3, but not #1:

```
preg_match(/(?<!thumb)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$/i, $file)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood third point correctly it means that it should end with all these file extensions. Considering this, the following will work

**1st Solution**

```
(?!^__|.*thumb\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg))(^.*)(?=\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vH1fF6/3)**

*Towards an efficient solution*

**2nd Solution**

```
^(?!__|.*thumb\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg))(.*(?=\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$).*$)
```

**3rd Solution** (suggested by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) in comments)

```
^(?!__|.*thumb\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg))(?=.*\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$).*
```

**4th Solution** (suggested by [Casimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) in comments)

```
^(?!__)(?:[^.\n]*\.)*+(?<!thumb\.)(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$
```

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/^(?!__|.*thumb\\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg))(?=.*\\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$)(.*)/m";
$str = "__abcd.jpg\nthumbabcd.gif\nthumbabcdthumb.jpg\nthumbs.jpg\nsomethumb.jpg\nthumb.jpg\nabcd.jpg\nabcd.jps"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/PzlMIA)**

Comment: Or `^(?!__|.*thumb\.)(?=.*\.(?:gif|jpg|png|jpeg)$).*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and you came up again with an efficient solution..i was just close to that

Comment: It is basically the same. Just avoid unnecessary backtracking anchoring the lookaheads before the generic subpattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yup..I still have a lot to learn regarding efficiency..thanks

Comment: @rock321987: This one works, now try to remove all useless things.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have updated the regex with newest solution but I am keeping all the three regex..thanks for test cases

Comment: The original lookbehind was a good idea. I would have written this: https://regex101.com/r/yF5vP8/1 or that: https://regex101.com/r/yF5vP8/2

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte the first thing that came to my mind was using lookahead.. yours is also good and efficient.. you should write it as an answer

Comment: Thanks, but no I can't. I must feed the bears in the forest.

Comment: Thanks guys! All solutions seem to work. Feeling like a kid in a candy store, I would likely go with @CasimiretHippolyte 's suggestion here https://regex101.com/r/yF5vP8/1, simply because it seems to have least steps. rock321987: feel free to add it to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be kind of an overkill, but you could come up with some **subroutines** for a better readability:

```
(?(DEFINE)
  # condition1
  (?<condition1>(?!(?:^__)))
  # condition2
  (?<condition2>(?!.*thumb))
  # allowed extensions 
  (?<ext>\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g)$)
)
^(?&condition1)(?&condition2).+(?&ext)$
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iV9eI0/3).